# What are the hardest specific parts of C++/C#/Java which show's you're an expert?

Tags: c#, java, c++

Just wondered what are the features of the three main programming languages which show you are an 'expert'? Im using this as a benchmark to improve my employability.

Am i right in saying for C++ the most difficult aspect to master is (smart) pointers?

Java seems much easier as memory is handled for you. I'm not entirely sure on C# either?

Comment: An expert is someone who has made all the mistakes before.  The best thing for employability is experience.

Comment: Good OO principles, consistent code formatting, etc. go a long way.  Poor programmers tend to be really sloppy about how they format their code, or make all their fields public.  (VS unfortunately defeats the code-formatting litmus test.  But you can always look for a bajillion blank lines all over the place -- it won't remove those.)

Comment: I have no clue what the "hardest" part of any of these languages is, much less if the hardest part is necessarily the same as the one which shows you're an expert.

But smart pointers are certainly not the hardest area of C++. They're extremely simple to use, not rocket science to write, and absolutely essential knownledge for **every** C++ programmer.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jalf, @Peter:  +1 for an unanswerable question, that's a pretty good answer

Comment: @cdhowie: I disagree on most counts. First, OO principles a. aren't necessarily "good", and b. say nothing about whether you're an expert at a specific language, which is what the OP asked about. And code formatting? Really? That has nothing to do with your expertise in a language. A trained monkey can indent code. That doesn't make you an expert (and likewise, writing ugly code doesn't necessarily mean you're not an expert)

Comment: @jalf: 95% of the really poor coders I have encountered in college and in workplaces have had their formatting all over the place.  If it compiled and ran, they were happy -- not caring about formatting or encapsulation...

Comment: @cdhowie: there's a big difference though between ruling out total scrubs, and trying to identify actual experts. OK, so consistent formatting indicates a tidy mind, and level of comfort about coding, and/or OCD. But I could be an ace C++ programmer, know stuff-all about Java, and my Java formatting would probably be pretty consistent (if not Java-standard, but then I can be an ace Java programmer and still think Java-standard indentation is lunatic).

Comment: OO principles are the first thing I'd look for.  Anyone can master the syntax of a language--that's level 1.  Knowing how to put it together without duplication is level 2.  Understanding how to optimize reading over writing is level 3, and OO tends to be more easily understood than most other methodologies I've seen.  Also learning things like explicit is better than implicit and that "Elegant" more often than not implies "Cryptic" are also pretty high up there.  Coding is easy--coding for humans to read, that's what I'd look for in an expert.

Comment: @cdhowie: So? 100% of the really poor coders I've encountered preferred to breathe oxygen. Correlation does not imply causation. As I understand the term, an "expert" is someone who knows a lot about the field. An expert C++ programmer is not someone who knows how to indent code, nor is it someone who prefers to eat organic matter for lunch, or is less than 140 years old. It is merely "someone who knows C++ extremely well".

Comment: What's more, if you're looking for an expert Java programmer, you *might* be able to get a decent approximation by looking for OO principles. For a C++ programmer, someone who knows OO principles, but not FP or generic programming principles is a huge warning sign. For C#, I'd also be more concerned about whether they know FP than OOP, partly because FP is a newer, more "advanced" addition to the language, and so it's what we should expect experts to be familiar with, whereas OOP was pretty much the first thing the language designers wrote on the whiteboard when they laid down the basics.

Comment: @jalf: And people who know a language particularly well also know that readability of their code is very important, where relative newbies (in my experience) simply don't care.  Correlation may not be causation, but it can be an indicator.  I guess this discussion is evidence of why the question was closed.

Comment: Pity such a good question is closed--perhaps it should be moved to the programmers site.

Comment: @Peter With many exceptions. Earlier this year I ran into a developer with over 15 years of experience mostly in the language/runtime he was tasked for developing in. His code was absolutely atrocious. Almost all his work was thrown away. The parts that stayed are being rewritten.

Comment: @cdhowie: I've seen a lot of of completely inept programmers (many of whom are, ironically, fairly good at OOP), who make a huge show of making their code look *pretty*. So it doesn't really tell us a lot. A good programmer should certainly care about making his code readable, but plenty of bad programmers care about the same thing, and do it very well.

Comment: @jalf: While good code formatting doesn't demonstrate your expertise, IMO, the opposite holds true. If it were up to me, I'd never even consider hiring someone that wrote poorly formatted code. I have to work with somebody that does this, and reading her code I have wished numerous times that it were a trained monkey that can do good formatting writing it instead of her. Now, if that monkey could also be taught how to add comments and pick meaningful variable names it'd be so much more valuable than this person.

Comment: Changing the subject for a moment, why was this question downvoted? That seems harsh. I completely agree with closing it, but there seems little reason for downvoting it as well.

Comment: @jalf: Those are probably the same people who put "C#.NET" and "web 2.0" on their resume...

Comment: @Praetorian: I dunno, I'd rather take someone who understands multi-threaded C++ and run `astyle` on their checkins until they learn to use the house format, than take someone who formats code beautifully and debug their race conditions. Obviously if offered both, take both, but I've certainly worked with good programmers who are a bit "relaxed" about formatting. Up to a point, I mean: it's not as though they had completely random indentation etc, but we occasionally pulled some quite special lines out of the company founder's code.

Comment: @Steve: That is exactly what I used to do, run `uncrustify` before ever looking at her code. Thankfully I rarely ever do this anymore, now I flat refuse to even glance at it and she's the only one that works on her bugs.

Comment: @Praetorian I take the opposite approach and choose to work on the hardest bugs in the most awful code. It may cause headaches, but it is good practice in figuring out how somebody very different from you thinks. I actually did it yesterday. After 20 minutes of figuring it out I found a field entered by a customer is never used, but will throw an error if left blank. Although the application does also set it, the headache was too strong to figure out why.

Comment: Why wasn't this migrated to programmers?